# Why is my linq to SQL query very slow?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I got this query that is very slow in a production environment. I would like to know why and if there is a better way to achieve the same result.

```
public async Task<Membership> FindByEmailByAccessL1OrL3OrL4Async(string email)
{
    return await (from m in this.Queryable()
                  where m.Email == email
                        && (m.RoleMemberships.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(RoleConstants.ACCESSGRANTEDL1ID)
                            || m.RoleMemberships.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(RoleConstants.ACCESSGRANTEDL3ID)
                            || m.RoleMemberships.Select(r => r.RoleId).Contains(RoleConstants.ACCESSGRANTEDL4ID))
                  select m).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

In short, the purpose of this query is to get a user membership by email and proceed to a login. More I got user memberships, more this query will be slow.

Thank you,

David

**Edit**

`this.Queryable()` is the equivalent of doing `select * from Memberships`.
`Membership` table has many roles, and a role has many memberships.

Also, memberships table takes up to 12 seconds to get the login information for 240 rows. I must filtering by role, because the email value isn't unique in the system. Only some roles have access to login and those roles will have unique email. This is why I have to filter. This query returns one membership to proceed to login, that has been selected with the query above. So no `IQueryable`, `IEnumerable` or `List`, just the `SingleOrDefault` value.

Comment: `this.Queryable()` ??? You don't provide much information.. What is `this` ?! What does `Queryable()` method return ? Show that code ?

Comment: Sorry about that! The code is inside a repository architecture. I gave more information in the Edit section.

Comment: We would probably need to see the SQL table definitions along with any indexes.

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL from the debugger?  It might provide you some insight...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the generated query is very bad, since you're doing the same thing multiple times which is:

```
m.RoleMemberships.Select(r => r.RoleId)
```

Instead, you can do that once using:

```
public Task<Membership> FindByEmailByAccessL1OrL3OrL4Async(string email)
{
    return (from m in this.Queryable()
            where m.Email == email
              && (m.RoleMemberships.Any(
                    r => r.RoleId == RoleConstants.ACCESSGRANTEDL1ID 
                      || r.RoleID == RoleConstants.ACCESSGRANTEDL3ID 
                      || r.RoleID == RoleConstants.ACCESSGRANTEDL4ID)
            select m).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

The above would make things better I guess. You can check the generated query in both cases using the debugger.

Also note that you don't need to await the result, just return the task and the caller would need to await for it.

Comment: " is very band" - do you mean "bad", "broad" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is much of data to load and EF is very slow mapping technology which creates interesting queries (you can see this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961(v=vs.110).aspx)).Do you have problems with performance?Maybe you should choose other mapping technology (stacks dapper for example [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)). When we made tests, it was in two times faster than EF.

Comment: How do you deduce that EF is in play here?

Comment: Once again, if we have large data it's not fast, that's why I think that it is this situation